# How to use the Calendar's Display Mode as a DataTrigger's Value

Tags: wpf, data-binding, enums, datatrigger

So I need to know how to set up a xmlns to let me use the CalendarMode in a Trigger's value.

I have tried using xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls", xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Calendar" and I've built the project each time, but I got error telling me that the CLR namespace is undefined and cannot be found.

Here is where I used it

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source=_Calendar, Path=Calendar.DisplayMode}">
  <DataTrigger.Value>
    <cal:CalendarMode>Month</cal:CalendarMode>
  </DataTrigger.Value>
  <Setter Property="Grid.Opacity" Value="1" />
</DataTrigger>
```

I guess I could just listen to the DisplayModeChanged event on the calendar but since I've been searching online for this solution all day, I'd really like to know how I can approach this problem in this way.

Any input will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

actually I did not understand exactly what you need. But I'll try to help.

the definition we see:

[image]

then able to use the xaml we have to do:

> xmlns:presentation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=PresentationFramework"

Now, if you want something to happen with a dependency property of the own control, you should use Triggers and not DataTriggers

Sample:

```
 <Calendar Height="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="83,112,0,0" Name="calendar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180">
        <Calendar.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Calendar">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SelectionMode" Value="{x:Static presentation:CalendarMode.Month}">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Calendar.Style>
    </Calendar>
```

Normally DataTriggers are used for objects created by you, which implementational INotifyPropertyChanged. Do not mess.

Now, if you want to change another control (when CalendarMode changes) you should do:

```
 <Calendar Height="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="83,112,0,0"
 Name="calendar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180"/>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=calendar1, Path=CalendarMode}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <presentation:CalendarMode>Month</presentation:CalendarMode>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
```

I suggest you read more about triggers, datatriggers and bindings.